# Get HWND from dxgi swapchain / d3d11 device

Tags: windows, directx, directx-11, dxgi

I've got a dxgiswapchain and d3d11device, and I would like to fetch a HWND from either of the two.

```cpp
void OnPresent(IDXGISwapChain *swapChain) {
    ID3D11Device *device = NULL;
    swapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (void**)&device);
}
```

How can I do so? I briefly remember it being possible with d3d9, so I'm not sure if the same is possible with dxgi/d3d11.

Comment: IDXGISwapChain::GetDesc will get you a DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC with a OutputWindow member of type HWND if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a shot, and hope that it works with imgui.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`IDXGISwapChain::GetDesc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiswapchain-getdesc) will give you the [swap chain description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/ns-dxgi-dxgi_swap_chain_desc), it contains the `HWND` to the output window:

```cpp
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
swapChain->GetDesc(&swapChainDesc);

swapChainDesc.OutputWindow; // the hwnd
```

Comment: If the swap chain was created from CreateSwapChainForComposition(), swapChainDesc.OutputWindow will be 0